# How to fix WillPopScope() not working for me

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I created two pages one is login and main page but i want close app from main page i am using `Willpopscope` but it is not working for me i have tried all things but the `onwillpop` method is not calling please help me thank you.

```
class main_page extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
  home: my_page(),
);
}
}

class my_page extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_my_pageState createState() => _my_pageState();
}

class _my_pageState extends State<my_page> {
 @override
void initState() {
check_login();
 super.initState();
}

Future check_login() async {
SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (preferences.getBool("islogin") == false)
  setState(() {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => MyApp(),
    ));
  });
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async=>false,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: Text(
        "Home",
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                  await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

              setState(() {
                sharedPreferences.setBool("islogin", false);
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => main_page(),
                ));
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              "Logout",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
            ))
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

I am also using `Shredprefrences` but i think it does not matter i want close app from my main_page please help me for this Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check out this answer and let me know if it works:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: SecondPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
            child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Move to second page after Login'),
          onPressed: () async {
            SharedPreferences preferences =
                await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

            preferences.setBool("islogin", true);
            // this will remove the login page after routing to the second page and then the stack will have only one page that is second page.
           // so later you can use the willpopscape 
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                ModalRoute.withName("/Home"));
          },
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SecondPageState createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    check_login();
    
    super.initState();
  }

  Future check_login() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (preferences.getBool("islogin") == null)

    //This above if statement will check if the parameter islogin is null then redirect to the login screeen
    // else if the value is not null then i will not enter the if statement
      setState(() {
        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
        ));
      });
  }

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {

    // This dialog will exit your app on saying yes
    return (await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
            content: new Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )) ??
        false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Home",
            style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                   SystemNavigator.pop();
                },
                child: Text(
                  "Logout",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sir what `ModalRoute.withName("/Home")` it does

Comment: If you specify the routes in the MaterialApp this is where it comes into the picture. but I have not used it I will just add it for you understanding.

Comment: Sir one problem is happening when i am going to main page after login app exiting working fine but after logout login screen is appear when i click the back button app is not exiting it going back to main page

Comment: This should be an actual behaviour after logout I will be redirected to the login screen.

Comment: Sir how to fix this

Comment: I want to close app after going to loginscreen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217199/discussion-between-prototype86-and-sagar-acharya).

Answer (score 15):

I was struggling with this problem, none of answers helped but finally I found the correct answer in `BackButton` widget source code.

When we use `WillPopScope` on top of our widget, we should use `maybePop` instead of `pop` method that forces the `Navigator` to pop the last pushed page in order to let the `WillPopScope` widget decides the next action.

```
Navigator.maybePop(context);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is answer `example_page` code

```
class exmp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_exmpState createState() => _exmpState();
}

class _exmpState extends State<exmp> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("example"),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Center(
        child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => my_example(),
              ),
              (route) => false);
        }),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

And this is my second page `my_example`

```
class my_example extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
  home: my_examp(),
);
 }
}

 class my_examp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _my_exampState createState() => _my_exampState();
 }

class _my_exampState extends State<my_examp> {
Future<bool> onbackpress() async{
return true;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: onbackpress,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("my_eaxmple"),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

The problem was i am pushing another page from my main page but i forget to remove first page for that i used the  `Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil( MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => my_example()(route) => false);` to remove the main page before navigate to another page

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you should use**

```
Future<bool> _willPopCallback() async {
    // await Show dialog of exit or what you want
    // then
    return true; //  
}


//then use in the build like
WillPopScope(child: new Scaffold(), onWillPop: _willPopCallback)
```

Comment: Not working sir `onbackpress` the page is coming on login_page

Comment: Not closing the app from another page

Comment: iOS swipe-back blocked if this returns false OR true.

Answer (score 0):

*I resolved this error as in my case I have a parent screen and in that, I have **PageView**. I was trying to call **WillPopScope** in one of my PageView and then I realized my parent have WillPopScope too.*

*That is why it is not calling WillPopScope of PageView*

Answer (score -5):

**don't use on Scaffold()**, wrap your MaterialApp as in the example

```
bool allowed = false;
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async {
    print('MJD POP TRYING TO GET BACK from login Page');
    return Future.value(allowed);
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Your App Title',
    theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: const MyLoginPage(title: 'Login Page'),
  ),
);
```